# Hangman in Python - Consonant Guessing Coding

Tags: python

**The Question**

```
guess_letter:
(str, str) -> str
```

The first parameter is the unguessed consonants and the second is the difficulty level. Return the consonant to be guessed next by the computer player. If level is EASY, the consonant to guess is randomly selected. If level is HARD, the consonant to guess the first consonant in PRIORITY_CONSONANTS that occurs in the first parameter.

```
PRIORITY_CONSONANTS = 'tnrslhdcmpfgybwvkqxjz'
EASY = 'E'
HARD = 'H'
```

Overall this project will create a functional Hangman game, this is one component of it which I have to code myself.

I don't know how to write this I made a small construct that I wanted to work around. But I honestly don't understand what to write.

I want that when the difficulty level is hard it to select the first consonant in priority consonants that appears in the parameter unguessed consonants
and when it is easy I want any random consonant to appear

```
guess_letters(unguessed_consonants, difficulty_level):
if difficulty_level == EASY:
if difficulty_level ==HARD:
```

Comment: Please write a good title. We need your help in writing good title for your question.

Comment: If the level is EASY, can the consonant which is randomly chosen be one of the PRIORITY_CONSONANTS?

Comment: It can be one of those consonants cause consonants are consonants right? Its just more random if its on Easy, on HARD it looks at the unguessed consonants and compares them with the priority consonants and guesses the first consonant seen

Comment: i dont know what to try exactly, i have written this for the HARD difficulty" for CONSONANTS in PRIORITY_CONSONANTS" but i don't really know how to expand beyond that or if what I'm doing can be expanded to what is required

Comment: I think that you put all of the consonants in English in PRIORITY_CONSONANTS. What are the other consonants to choose from?

Comment: One way to simplify this is, `unguessed_consonants = PRIORTITY_CONSTANTS` at the start, and then remove each letter from `guessable` as it is guessed (randomly or by priority). That is, the constant is only used as the primer for the sequence (and priority) of letters to guess. Then the problem/solution for "H" just becomes: take the first unguessed consonant (which is arranged by priority) and try to use it as the guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import random

EASY = 'E'
HARD = 'H'
PRIORITY_CONSONANTS = 'tnrslhdcmpfgybwvkqxjz'
EASY_CONSONANTS = '' # what should be here?

def guess_letters(unguessed_consonants, difficulty_level):
    if difficulty_level == EASY:
        search_set = EASY_CONSONANTS
    elif difficulty_level == HARD:
        search_set = PRIORITY_CONSONANTS

    for con in unguessed_consonants:
        if con in search_set:
             return con
```

In response to the comment by Nadia:

> kk that worked better except if i input 'zk' on hard it will give me z instead of k k comes before z in the PRIORITY_CONSONANTS so the output should be k

In that case, search_set should be iterated over first:

```
    for con in search_set:
        if con in unguessed_consonants:
             return con
```

Comment: that works well for the EASY level, but for HARD its supposed to look at the first parameter( say thats 'htf')

out of those 3 consonants the first one to appear in PRIORITY_CONSONANTS is 't'
thus it will guess 't'

Comment: the EASY_CONSONANTS would be the same as the priority consonants

Comment: kk that worked better except if i input 'zk' on hard it will give me z instead of k

k comes before z in the PRIORITY_CONSONANTS so the output should be k

Answer (score 0):

I won't give you the answer here. But you can achieve the "HARD" mode using str.index

```
>>> 'abcd'.index('b')
1
```

Check the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.index) for more documentation

Comment: i honestly have no idea how to use that